# Trouble Connecting to Remote HBase in Java

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to connect to a remote HBase from Java.  hbase shell works fine.  But when I try to connect in code I get errors.  Here is my hbase-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://some.ip.address:8020/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>some.ip.address</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.user.region.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.rest.port</name>
    <value>9999</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Here are what the errors look like:

```
13/07/08 16:03:36 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)

13/07/08 16:03:37 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)

13/07/08 16:03:37 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

Am I missing a value in my hbase-site.xml?  If hbase shell works fine, why cant the code connect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my hbase-site.xml was not on my classpath.